Mounting offset impact on IMU measurement
I have IMU sensor to detect euler angles. This sensor is mounted with offset from the center X-axis(forward direction) i.e it is almost on right edge.
I want to understand what will be impact of this offset on final euler angles.
How to compensate or realign it with the target alignment.
Any suggestions, directions will be helpfull.

A 6-axis IMU by itself cannot measure orientation.  A 9-axis (gyro + compass + accelerometer) can do so, but poorly.  If your structure is rigid, the relative orientation of each part to any other part is constant.  So: you need to edit your question for detail.  What sort of IMU are you using (6-axis or 9?  Magnetometer?).  If you're using some package that's calling orientation data "IMU", what is the package?  What other sensors are you using to complete the orientation equation (GPS?  SLAM?).  What algorithm are you using to merge sensor data?

@TimWescott I have 6 axis acclero and gyro sensor. The target is to measure roll and pitch in dynamic environment for 2 wheelers. No external sensors like gps. Fusion algorithm not explored yet.

I put edit your question in bold to encourage you to edit your question.  Stackexchange is different from other forums -- we want the question itself to be complete and "closed" (i.e. -- one that has one or more correct answers).  Specifically, please don't leave important information buried in the comments -- put it into the question (or answer).
